# Play 2.0.3 application.context / sub url in play

Tags: playframework-2.0

where is a lot of topik about that but i nevere understoun d wich version implement the  application.contex
and it does nothing on 2.0.3

First i succeffuly use play 1.2.4 parameter like this:

```
    http.port=9004
    http.path=/Zenith2
    XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1
```

In play 2.0.3 i try this:

```
    application.context="/Zenith2"
    application.address="127.0.0.1"
    application.port="9088"
```

-> bind in 9000 (default)

I also try:

```
    play2 start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.port=9088 -Dapplication.context=/Zenith2/
```

-> bind in 9000 (default)

all this syntax is issue from google groups and stackoverflom other topic

thanks  for any help

Answer (score 1):

As stated by James Roper on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/FfM_BA7HsbM/xMnTppxOGHoJ) : `Play 2.0.*` does not yet support running on a different context